# Is the "4GB patch" of any use in real life?

Tags: memory, memory-management, malloc, out-of-memory, heap-memory

And if so, how. I'm talking about this [4GB Patch](http://www.ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php).

On the face of it, it seems like a pretty nifty idea: on Windows, each 32-bit application normally only has access to 2GB of address space, but if you have 64-bit Windows, you can enable a little flag to allow a 32-bit application to access the full 4GB. The page gives some examples of applications that might benefit from it.

HOWEVER, most applications seem to assume that memory allocation is always successful. Some applications do check if allocations are successful, but even then can at best quit gracefully on failure. I've never in my (short) life come across an application that could fail a memory allocation and still keep going with no loss of functionality or impact on correctness, and I have a feeling that such applications are from extremely rare to essentially non-existent in the realm of desktop computers. With this in mind, it would seem reasonable to assume that any such application would be programmed to not exceed 2GB memory usage under normal conditions, and those few that do would have been built with this magic flag already enabled for the benefit of 64-bit users.

So, have I made some incorrect assumptions? If not, how does this tool help in practice? I don't see how it could, yet I see quite a few people around the internet claiming it works (for some definition of works).

Comment: I *want* to close this as too opinion based but I'm also interested in an answer...maybe rework the question to ask a more fact-based one?

Answer (score 1):

Your troublesome assumptions are these ones:

> Some applications do check if allocations are successful, but even then can at best quit gracefully on failure. I've never in my (short) life come across an application that could fail a memory allocation and still keep going with no loss of functionality or impact on correctness, and I have a feeling that such applications are from extremely rare to essentially non-existent in the realm of desktop computers.

There do exist applications that do better than "quit gracefully" on failure. Yes, functionality will be impacted (after all, there wasn't enough memory to continue with the requested operation), but many apps will at least be able to stay running - so, for example, you may not be able to add any more text to your enormous document, but you can at least save the document in its current state (or make it smaller, etc.)

> With this in mind, it would seem reasonable to assume that any such application would be programmed to not exceed 2GB memory usage under normal conditions, and those few that do would have been built with this magic flag already enabled for the benefit of 64-bit users.

The trouble with this assumption is that, in general, an application's memory usage is determined by what you do with it. So, as over the past years storage sizes have grown, and memory sizes have grown, the sizes of files that people want to operate on have also grown - so an application that worked fine when 1GB files were unheard of may struggle now that (for example) high definition video can be taken by many consumer cameras.

Putting that another way: applications that used to fit comfortably within 2GB of memory no longer do, because people want do do more with them now.

Answer (score 0):

I do think the following extract from your link of [4 GB Patch](http://www.ntcore.com/4gb_patch.php) pretty much explains the reason of how and why it works.

> Why things are this way on x64 is easy to explain. On x86 applications have 2GB of virtual memory out of 4GB (the other 2GB are reserved for the system). On x64 these two other GB can now be accessed by 32bit applications. In order to achieve this, a flag has to be set in the file's internal format. This is, of course, very easy for insiders who do it every day with the CFF Explorer. This tool was written because not everybody is an insider, and most probably a lot of people don't even know that this can be achieved. Even I wouldn't have written this tool if someone didn't explicitly ask me to.

And to expand on [CFF](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php),

> The CFF Explorer was designed to make PE editing as easy as possible,
>   but without losing sight on the portable executable's internal
>   structure. This application includes a series of tools which might
>   help not only reverse engineers but also programmers. It offers a
>   multi-file environment and a switchable interface.

And to quote a Microsoft insider, Larry Miller of Microsoft MCSA on a [blog](http://www.jaloonz.com/2008/04/enabling-large-address-aware-for-games.html) post about patching games using the tool,

> Under 32 bit windows an application has access to 2GB of VIRTUAL
>   memory space. 64 bit Windows makes 4GB available to applications.
>   Without the change mentioned an application will only be able to
>   access 2GB.
>
> This was not an arbitrary restriction. Most 32 bit applications simply
>   can not cope with a larger than 2GB address space. The switch
>   mentioned indicates to the system that it is able to cope. If this
>   switch is manually set most 32 bit applications will crash in 64 bit
>   environment.
>
> In some cases the switch may be useful. But don't be surprised if it
>   crashes.

And finally to add from MSDN - [Migrating 32-bit Managed Code to 64-bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973190.aspx),

> There is also information in the PE that tells the Windows loader if
>   the assembly is targeted for a specific architecture. This additional
>   information ensures that assemblies targeted for a particular
>   architecture are not loaded in a different one. The C#, Visual Basic
>   .NET, and C++ Whidbey compilers let you set the appropriate flags in
>   the PE header. For example, C# and THIRD have a /platform:{anycpu,
>   x86, Itanium, x64} compiler option.
>
> **Note**: While it is technically possible to modify the flags in the PE header of an assembly after it has been compiled, Microsoft does not recommend doing this.

Finally to answer your question - **how does this tool help in practice?**

Since you have malloc in your tags, I believe you are working on unmanaged memory. This patch would mostly result in invalid pointers as they become twice the size now, and almost all other primitive  datatypes would be scaled by a factor of 2X. 
But for managed code since all these are handled by the CLR in .NET, this would mean really helpful and would not have much problems unless you are dealing with any of the following :

- Invoking platform APIs via p/invoke
- Invoking COM objects
- Making use of unsafe code
- Using marshaling as a mechanism for sharing information
- Using serialization as a way of persisting state

To ***summarize***, being a programmer I would not use the tool to convert my application and rather would migrate it myself by changing build targets. being said that if I have a exe that can do well like games with more RAM, then this is worth a try.